# python flask does not work behind HTTP proxy

Tags: flask, proxy

I suspect the issue is the HTTP proxy in the server. But I am not sure.

I set up a hello world Flask app on Ubuntu, I was able to access the page by

```
elinks http://localhost:5000, # and
elinks http://127.0.0.1:5000, # but not
```

## But NOT

```
elinks http://<server_ip_in_LAN>:5000 # I was also not able to remote access the page on another machine
```

Then I looked at my proxy settings, in /etc/environment, it has the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
https_proxy="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
ftp_proxy="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
git_proxy="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
FTP_PROXY="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
GIT_PROXY="http://proxy-ip:8080/"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Further, I use ufw to control the firewall, port 5000 is allowed from anywhere.
And I was able to see the following by running nmap -Pn localhost

```
$ nmap -Pn localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-04 21:09 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3000/tcp open  ppp
5000/tcp open  upnp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds

However, if I run

```
nmap -Pn <server_ip_in_LAN>,
```

the "5000/tcp open upnp" line was missing, implying the port number seems only open to my localhost, but not open to LAN.

Why? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flask often use internal host:

> 127.0.0.1

. So you can connect by server_ip_in_LAN by change host IP:

```
app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar kind of issue when I was trying to set my first pycharm project for flask.

Things you need to check

- HTTP Proxy(if you are behind a proxy)
- Verify the proxy details if proxy added
- Check for port if not already used.
- for flask specific(if you want to run on specific host and port)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5000', debug=True)

It gets started on 0.0.0.0 you can change it to localhost.